# How do you run nx serve with node --trace-warnings?

Tags: node.js, nrwl-nx

I start my app with

```
yarn nx serve my-api
```

There is an error in the build of an unknown origin that is being obfuscated by node. The console output says "Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created". How do I run `yarn nx serve` in conjunction with `--trace-warnings`? I want to get the stack trace so that I can find my error.

Answer (score 11):

`node --trace-warnings node_modules/.bin/nx serve my-api`

Alternatively, you could include this code within your application:

```
process.on('warning', e => console.warn(e.stack));
```

Comment: How to run `node --trace-warnings node_modules/.bin/nx serve my-api` with `nx run some-lib:test`?

Running `node --trace-warnings ./node_modules/.bin/nx angular:test` gives me following error: `node_modules\.bin\nx:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`. I am using Node v20.10.0

Comment: It looks like shell code is being passed to node. What is the output of `head -1 node_modules/.bin/nx`?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a runtime argument in the project.json as follow:

````
```
"serve": {
  "executor": "@nx/js:node",
  "defaultConfiguration": "development",
  "options": {
    "watch": false,
    "buildTarget": "api-node:build"
  },
  "configurations": {
    "development": {
      "buildTarget": "api-node:build:development",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--trace-warnings"
      ]
    },
    "production": {
      "buildTarget": "api-node:build:production"
    }
  }
},
```
````